# How to disable button only if the request is successful - otherwise keep button enabled in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, setstate

Im trying to disable a button only if the api request is successful, otherwise if it is not successful, the button should be enabled still. I have the following state field.

```
this.state = {
  buttonDisabled: false,
};
```

Here is my button:

```
<Button type="button" disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} onClick={this.send} variant="outlined" color="primary">
          Send
 </Button>
```

However, for some reason, the button is disabled for 10 seconds in both cases. Passed and failed response from the api. Is there something off here?

Comment: How do you render your button?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I will update my post now to show, thanks!

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros ok, i updated my post to include the button

Comment: Without seeing the sendSMS() function it's hard to tell, but I imagine the promise is resolving to a response object, which would be there whether or not the call to the API was successful

Comment: Are you sure `sendSms()` throws an error if the request is not successful?

Comment: @BrendanBond I updated the code to show the contents of sendSms(). Thanks

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Ill find that out for you in a sec

Comment: So if there is an error in the response, there will be an error object inside the data object, otherwise it just returns a status of pending inside the data object @ZsoltMeszaros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sendSms() function returns an axios `Response` object. Therefore, the `data` object will always be populated and an error is never thrown.

```
sendSmsCode = async () => {
         const { actions } = this.props;
    
         sendSms(phone)
           .then((data) => {
             // the data object is always populated with the response object and never throws an error
             // therefore, this function will always set the state to disabled
             this.setState({
               requestSmsDisabled: true
             }, () => {
               actions.showSmsNotification(data);
             });
           })
           // this is never invoked
           .catch(err => actions.showSmsNotification(err));
    
         setTimeout(() => {
           this.setState({
             requestSmsDisabled: false
           });
         }, 10000);
       };
```

You need to check for an error in the response from your axios call, either in the sendSms() function or the sendSmsCode() function, something like:

```
async function sendSms(phone) {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      phone
    },
    url: `${API_ROOT}/sms`
  };
  // there are a number of ways to do this, it all depends on how you want to do it
  const response = await axios(options);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return response.data;
  } else {
    // do something to indicate an error, e.g. throw an error to get caught in your .catch() statement or return an error message
  }
}
```